# How to edit the text prase by Json after assigning it to the TextFormFeild in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-textformfield, texteditingcontroller

I prase a json and assign the text to a TextFormField. I want to edit that text again. How to do it. I tried, but again the text displayed by json is still displaying.

```
    var disConroller = TextEditingController();
    disConroller.text = snapshot.data[0].note
```

> My TextTextFormField

```
 TextFormField(
            maxLines: null,
            minLines: null,
            controller: disConroller, // enterd text
            decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "type here..",
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide:
            BorderSide(width: 2.0)),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide:
            BorderSide(width: 1.0),)
```

Answer (score 0):

by seeing your code it is hard to ans but if have parsed your json correctly decoded it and converted to a string then then assign that string to the controller change the state and this will work i can only tell this much with the code you have shared